# Can I setup a DNS alias to point to a a machine behind the firewall?

Tags: domain-name-system, remote-desktop, routing, port-forwarding

A little confusing question, but here's what I'm trying to do.

I have port forwarding setup so that we can use 1 static IP to RDP into different machines behind our firewall.

For instance

My Dev Machine
173.165.1.188:3660 -> 192.168.0.1:3389

One of our internal servers:
173.165.1.188:3661 -> 192.168.0.2:3389

What I was hoping to be able to do is to setup a dns entry that would handle the mapping for us so instead of:

173.165.1.188:3660 to get to my pc I could go to mypc.mydomain.com

Is this possible?

*Disclamer: Real IP's not used here to protect the innocent.*

**UPDATE**

If it wont work using port forwarding, is there some other option I can use? Can I setup local dns entries that take mypc.mydomain.com and map it to an internal ip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this won't work - DNS entries only relate to whole IP addresses, not IP:port combinations.

The only practical way to make this work using hostnames alone is to get more IP addresses from your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely possible. DNS only points to a particular IP address - naturally it does not care if the IP address is behind a firewall. DNS will work if the IP is assigned to a server that crashed, or even if the IP was not assigned.

#### Couple more points

- I could imagine a fancy DNS server setup that checks the connectivity before giving you an answer but that's rear
- No ports in DNS (as Alnitak mentioned)